# SQL Job not producing same output as the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I run this query to get landesk info. It returns 4 columns of info that I want but when I try to set it up as a scheduled job the output doesn't format the results the same. I'd like a column for each. Under Steps I just run the same query and under advanced I output the file. Another twist is, why can I not send the output to a share? I can only select drives on the server. SQL Server 2008 R2

```
SELECT DISTINCT A0.DISPLAYNAME AS "Device Name"
    ,A1.OSTYPE AS "OS Name"
    ,A0.DOMAINNAME AS "Domain Name"
    ,A0.HWLASTSCANDATE AS "Last Hardware Scan Date"
FROM Computer A0(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN Operating_System A1(NOLOCK) ON A0.Computer_Idn = A1.Computer_Idn
WHERE (A0.DEVICENAME IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY A0.DISPLAYNAME
```

Comment: Always a little tough to figure these things out. Snapping a few screenshots of your scheduler might help. Good luck, I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: Under General > Category I changed it to Full-Text and all of the columns are returned but not in the format I am looking for. It looks like all of the Headers are in 1 Row device name, os name, domain, scan date. I want them to be separated into columns like the query result produces.

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: Hm... sounds strange... did you try to concat the columns together with a "tab" in between? Like Displayname + char(9) + ...?

Comment: sstan - Landesk Admin console provided the T-SQL for me after I chose what I wanted in the GUI. If I just Query the db the result is in 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to get the consistency you are looking for as well the ability to output to network locations, that you will want to set up an ssis package and run that under the agent.

If you are stuck with this method see if the files are tab delimited, you are probably getting 4 columns but in a text editor its not obvious.

Comment: This solution has now led me to this problem where the ssis package executes the way it's supposed to but when I run it from the SQL Server Agent Job it fails.

Comment: Something about The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS no OLE provider is available. Exporting the file as a csv or txt file produces the same incorrect output as above so running it from SSIs isn't solving the issue unfortunately.

Comment: You just need to set the 64bit runtime to false when running from sql agent and the excel will work.

Comment: I am exporting it to a flat file and it works from ssis. Now the issue is formatting again. The query I provided above produces 4 columns. When I create the SSIS package it again asks for formatting like delimiters and commas. How do I tell SSIS to just reproduce what the Query is fetching? I think that will solve the issue.

Comment: by default it will be comma delimited (CSV).  If you open a CSV in excel or other appropriate editor it will show the distinct columns.  I am not sure what exactly you are looking for.  Even is ssms the data in the background is not 'formatted'.  It does not look like four distinct columns until ssms renders in the results window.

Comment: I guess the real questions is - what do you want to do with the data after export?  A file another system can import, a report, other use?

Comment: I would like the end result to be a csv with 4 columns so I can read it into a PowerShell script that will give a report based on what PowerShell pulls from Active Directory and compare it to what's in Landesk. The T-SQL query produces exactly what I need. 4 Columns. In SSMS Export Data Wizard when I preview the output it shows 4 columns but the file doesn't get written that way from SSIS unless I export it as Excel then I run into some Excel Connection Manager Error. Flat file wants to delimit what's already formatted by the query. Thanks for answering, everyone.

Comment: Joe C I will try your recommendation and disable 64 bit runtime and see what happens.

Comment: Checking "run under 32 bit mode" in the execution options of the job didn't work for me.